# what is different between ANDROID_HOME & ANDROID_SDK_HOME

Tags: java, android, sdk

I have 2 directory that look same,

> ANDROID_HOME=C:\Android\sdk
>
> ANDROID_SDK_HOME=C:\Users[user]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

whats the different?
can I set it in one dir?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables):

**ANDROID_HOME**

`ANDROID_HOME`, points to the SDK installation directory. This has been deprecated, use `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` instead.

> If you continue to use it, the following rules apply:
>
> - If `ANDROID_HOME` is defined and contains a valid SDK installation, its value is used instead of the value in ANDROID_SDK_ROOT.
> - If `ANDROID_HOME` is not defined, the value in ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is used.
> - If `ANDROID_HOME` is defined but does not exist or does not contain a valid SDK installation, the value in `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` is used instead.

**ANDROID_SDK_HOME**

The root of the user-specific directory where all configuration and AVD content is stored

> can I set it in one dir?

Ideally you shouldn't, since they serve different purpose.

Comment: ANDROID_SDK_HOME must be the worst variable naming ever... Extremely vague and easy to confuse with ANDROID_HOME.

Comment: The android docs: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables, mention that `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` is deprecated in favor of `ANDROID_HOME`

Comment: Like @Sri stated. this answer says opposite of the official docs regarding deprecated variable.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like the accepted answer is no longer valid. The *current* docs say:

```
 ANDROID_SDK_ROOT, which also points to the SDK installation directory, is deprecated.
```

Source table: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables#envar

Answer (score 0):

I got this message -

com.android.prefs.AndroidLocationsException: ANDROID_SDK_HOME is set to the root of your SDK: D:\AndroidStudio\SDK
ANDROID_SDK_HOME was meant to be the parent path of the preference folder expected by the Android tools.
It is now deprecated.

To set a custom preference folder location, use ANDROID_USER_HOME.

It should NOT be set to the same directory as the root of your SDK.
To set a custom SDK location, use ANDROID_HOME.